# How to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript from within a dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, scriptmanager

In various project I used the following code to open a document in a window, from an aspx page :

```
public void viewDocument(string strLink, System.Web.UI.Control ctrlPanel)
{
    string strScript;
    strScript = "var w=window.open('" + strLink + "','zz');window.focus();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(ctrlPanel, ctrlPanel.GetType(), "ShowInfo", strScript, true);
}
```

and everything is working fine.
I decided to create a toolbox, i.e. a project that contains only functions that can be usefull in many projects. That toolbox is now a dll referenced by the projects.
My problem : my viewDocument function doesn't work anymore. I do not have any javascript error, nothing. In debug mode, I can see that it runs through the "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript" command, but no window is opened.
Can someone explain me what I missed ?

Comment: I haven't played with this for a long time but if I remember well, I think your web page is supposed to have a ScriptManager control. Have you made sure that is the case?

Comment: Yes, I have one in the MasterPage.

Comment: Have you tried calling ScriptManager.GetCurrent()? What do you get? That might help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: I tried : 'code' var scriptManager = System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);
                        scriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(ctrlPanel, ctrlPanel.GetType(), "ShowInfo", strScript, true); 'code' but this raise an error : ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript cannot be accessed by an instance reference. Use a type name instead.
                    }
                }

Comment: That means you have an instance of the ScriptManager class called "ScriptManager". This is a static method so try calling it like this: System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet. Then you don't need to send `System.Web.UI.Control` as variable.

```
public void viewDocument(string strLink)
{
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

    string strScript = "var w=window.open('" + strLink + "','zz');window.focus();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "ShowInfo", strScript, true);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem ! Thank you and thanks to Juan too !